# Colorbox issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, loading, colorbox

When viewing colorbox in chrome, it loads fully on the first load of the page and then when I refresh the page the display cocks up:

http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4474/censornetissue.jpg

Any clue why this could be happening?

It works fine after if I clear the cache.

Here is the URL for the page:

test.webforma.co.uk/censornet/product_page.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of validation errors on that page, some of the kind which can cause particular trouble, like missing end tags and duplicate class attributes.

I don't know if that's the problem or not, but I'd start by fixing them.

Update:

I see it now, now I realise what I'm supposed to be clicking on.

Is this the solution:

http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/msg/4425b37ded9c66dd

(Include colorbox CSS before colorbox JS)

Comment: Hi will, cheers for the quick answer. I fixed the HTML errors (mostly alt tags), but to no avail, even though the site is fully HTML valid. Any other ideas?

Comment: It looks OK here - well, it's a bit odd, with top half of the window being a rounded-corner, 1000-ish pixel wide section and on a white background, and the bottom half being a full width product info section.  But it doesn't smash-up on refresh or anything.

Comment: Thats strange. I'm using Chrome v 9.0.576.0 dev and the client is also experiencing it using Chrome v 7.0.517.44 ... its weird how it works after CTRL + 5

Comment: The bit I've added about the CSS is actually in the colorbox troubleshooting section - definitely worth a try, as do you have have them round the 'wrong' way at the moment